# Linear Algebra Problems?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there any good reference for difficult problems in linear algebra? Because I keep running into easily stated linear algebra problems that I feel I *should* be able to solve, but don't see any obvious approach to get started.

Here's an example of the type of problem I am thinking of: Let $A, B$ be $n\times n$ matrices, set $C = AB-BA$, prove that if $AC=CA$ then $C$ is nilpotent. (I saw this one posed on the KGS Go Server)

Ideally, such a reference would also contain challenging problems (and techniques to solve them) about orthogonal matrices, unitary matrices, positive definiteness... hopefully, all harder than the one I wrote above.

Comment: Here's another example perhaps: say A and B are real n x n matrices,and A^2+B^2=AB. If AB-BA is invertible, prove that n is a multiple of 3. Are there really books that can teach you how to solve such poroblems??

Comment: "Are there really books that can teach you how to solve such problems??" Books about the representation theory of Lie algebras perhaps. At least this is where most of such problems come from. Not that I would know the techniques for solving them, however. Except the standard tricks (a matrix $A$ over a field of characteristic zero is nilpotent if and only if every k = 1, 2, 3, ... satisfies Tr (A^k) = 0, etc.)

Comment: @Darij: feel free to use any standard result you like from the representation theory of Lie algebras to resolve my question about real n x n matrices above!

Comment: Vote to close as no longer relevant, in view of the last "answers" and to a lesser extent since today it might be closed anyway. 

Comment: @Kevin:  Why not post it as its own question?

Comment: I should now perhaps add that the two spammy answers that motivated me to write above comment are now gone. Of course I have no problem with the now recent ones. 

Comment: @Kevin, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299651/square-matrices-satisfying-certain-relations-must-have-dimension-divisible-by-3/314528#314528 for a somewhat systematic approach.

Answer (score 20):

Google will find for you V. Prasolov's *Problems and Theorems in Linear Algebra*, which has beautiful more or less hard problems.

Answer (score 11):

[Halmos's Linear Algebra Problem Book](http://books.google.com/books?id=DQP3AIlrCP0C&lpg=PP1&client=firefox-a&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=&f=false).  It contains problems, then hints, then solutions.  There is a variety of difficulty levels, and some of the problems are very easy, but some are challenging.  The book is designed to be a supplement for learning linear algebra by problem solving, so it may not have the focus you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, Halmos is a very good reference. You will also find some nice problems in [Berkeley problems in mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387008926) and on the website of the [International Mathematics Competition](http://www.imc-math.org/)

Comment: Sorry to say but the Berkeley problems book is mostly spam. Most of the problems there are either well-known or boring. Actually, exam questions and problems which make one learn something are two totally different kinds of problems; the former are supposed to check one's skills, while the latter should develop them. As for the IMC, I agree - that contains many good questions, just as the [url=http://vjimc.osu.cz/index.php?page=history]Vojtech Jarnik[/url] and the [url=http://www.mat.itu.edu.tr/gungor/IMO/www.kalva.demon.co.uk/putnam.html]Putnam contest[/url].

Comment: I didn't say that all problems are interesting. But I found some of the problems in the book interesting. Not all of them are standard questions, using standard techniques...!

Answer (score 6):

In addition to those mentioned above, there is *Linear Algebra: Challenging Problems for Students* by Fuzhen Zhang

Answer (score 4):

Let me introduce you a good reference, IMAGE. At the end of IMAGE there is a section called IMAGE Problem Corner: Solutions of Old Problems and New Problems. You may enjoy solving these problems and read solutions by others.
See http://www.math.technion.ac.il/iic/IMAGE/

Answer (score 3):

you could also browse the linear algebra section of [AoPS](http://www.mathlinks.ro/index.php?f=349).

Answer (score 3):

I will take this opportunity to post  my favorite linear algebra problem.  I call it 0 not equal to 1.

Let A be an nxn 0-1 matrix with nonzero determinant.  Show that there is a 1 in every row and in every column of A, and further there is a permutation matrix P so that PA has a diagonal of all 1's.

Let B be an nxn 0-1 matrix with nonzero determinant. We cannot show that there is a 0 in every row and in every column, so assume B also has this property.  Are there nxn permutation matrices P and Q such that PBQ has all 0's on the diagonal?  If not, how small a trace can one guarantee?

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.03.03

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to know a little bit of Italian, another good resource is *Problemi risolti di algebra lineare*, by Broglia, Fortuna, Luminati.

(By the way, if you have never done it, reading a math book in another language is often easier than it seems at first sight)