# Understanding the countable ordinals up to $\epsilon_{0}$

Tags: set-theory, ordinal-numbers, visualization

in a recent MO question, [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40920/what-if-current-foundations-of-mathematics-are-inconsistent%20%22link%22), discussing the current foundations of mathematics, the author linked a video lecture by Prof.  Voevodsky, which argues against the principle of $\epsilon_{0}$-induction used in Gentzen's proof of the consistency of PA.

In discussions arising from the question, some people commented that imagining an infinite descending chain in $\epsilon_{0}$ is "crazy".

I would like to understand better this ordinal, since I actually don't know exactly how to depict it in my mind.

I have clear in my mind the order associated with the finite ordinals. I use in my mind a notation of the following kind:

$1 = I$

$2=  II$

$3=  III$

$4=  IIII$

$\omega = (III\dots)$

$\omega+1= (III\dots)I$

$\omega +2 = (III\dots)II$

$\omega + \omega= \omega \cdot 2= (III\dots)(III\dots)$

In general I understand $\alpha + \beta$ as the juxtaposition of the two representations.

$\omega\cdot 3 = (III\dots)(III\dots)(III\dots)$

$\omega\cdot \omega = \omega^{2} = \big( (III\dots)(III\dots)(III\dots)\dots\big)$

In general I understand $\alpha \cdot \beta$, by replacing each $I$ symbol in $\beta$ with the representation of $\alpha$. So

$\omega^{3}=\omega^{2}\cdot \omega = \big( \omega^{2} \omega^{2}  \omega^{2}  \dots \big)$

This allows me to *visualize* every ordinal of the form $\omega^{n}\cdot m + k$, with $n,m,k$ naturals (i.e finite ordinals). So far I have absolutely no doubt that there are no infinite descending chain in ordinals of the form $\omega^{n}\cdot m + k$.

However I start having problem with the ordinal $\omega^{\omega}= \bigsqcup_{n<\omega}\omega^{n}$. Do you have any idea on how to visualize $\omega^{\omega}$ is a way consistent with the representation used above (which i actually found [here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/acl2/current/O-P.html)) ?

Anyway, looking at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Exponentiation), I still manage to visualize $\omega^{\omega}$ as the set of infinite strings of natural number, having only finitely many digits different from $0$.

Still I have no doubt that there are no infinite descending chain in  $\omega^{\omega}$.

Perhaps i might be able to understand $\omega^{\omega^{\omega}}$, namely the set of infinite strings labeled with elements of $\omega^{\omega}$, having only finitely many elements different from $0$.
Or (i guess) equivalently a $\omega\times\omega$ square labeled with naturals, where only finitely many columns are different from $0^{\omega}$, and all of these non constant-$0$ columns, contains only finitely many digits different from $0$.

However I do not know how to visualize $\epsilon_{0}$. I mean I know that the elements of $\epsilon_{0}$ can be represented by finite-branching finite trees labeled with natural numbers, but that doesn't give me a strong intuition about the fact that no infinite chain exists, so I guess its not a great picture (or at least I do not understand it properly, yet).

**Questions**

A) Could you suggest a way to visualize $\omega^{\omega^{\omega}}$? It should be in such a way to convince me about the fact that there are no infinite down-chain.

B) Could you suggest a way to visualize $\epsilon_{0}$, again arguing that it should be very clear that there are no infinite down-chain.

C) Could you please state your opinion about Prof. Voevodsky, which argues against the principle of $\epsilon_{0}$-induction used in Gentzen's? 
This shouldn't be a duplicate of the previous, wider thread [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40920/what-if-current-foundations-of-mathematics-are-inconsistent%20%22link%22), I'm only interested in this little bit of Voevodsky's talk.

Thank you in advance,

bye

matteo

Comment: There is an interpretation in terms of sorted lists here: http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/12/07/the-technical-part-of-godels-proof/

Comment: Duplicate? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5065/what-is-induction-up-to-epsilon-0

Comment: Thanks Qiaochou an Yuan!
I apologize if this is considered to be a duplicate. Even if I tried to search for epsilon_{0} in MO, i couldn't find that Question, which I think it's indeed quite close to mine.
Also Qiaochu's proposed link comes from the same question, so I guess you might consider to close this one, if you think that's appropriate.
thanks again!

Comment: I don't know if this qualifies as "visualization", but Takeuti's book has a very explicit and lengthy discussion of precisely this issue.

Comment: @ChristianRemling, do you remember which book? (Is it Introduction to Axiomatic Set Theory?)

Comment: I don't know if this counts as visualization, but with the Cantor Normal Form you know that $\varepsilon_0$ is the set of finite trees written with the symbols $\omega$ and $0$ ($0$ at the leaves, and the tree must have certain order, but anyway...). So when I imagine a descending sequence I know that the (finite) height of the trees is non increasing. And with some effort you can convince yourself that it must eventually decrease.

Comment: Are you sure that being convinced of the inexistence of an infinite descending chain is enough for you? In Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, you can prove that any well-ordered set has no infinite decending chain but you cannot prove that every totally ordered set without an infinite descending chain is well-ordered. You can however deduce it from the axiom of dependent choice. I think you want the stronger statement that epsilon zero is well ordered. Maybe since you know how to count all the notations you suspect are notations for all the ordinal numbers less than epsilon zero, you know that the

Comment: axiom of dependent choice holds for that set so it suffices to show that it has no infinite descending chain. Are you sure that's good enough? It still might not give you a good intuitive feel of what epsilon zero really is.

Comment: Here's a sequence. You start with 0. The next term is an operation on ordinal numbers. The one after that is an operation on operations on ordinal numbers. Then we have an operation on operations on operations on ordinal numbers. The level 1 operation is the successor operation, the operation that assigns to each ordinal number the smallest ordinal number that is larger than it. Next we have a level 2 operation defined as follows. It assigns to each level 1 operation the operation that assigns to each ordinal number that smallest ordinal number that's larger than any ordinal number that can be

Comment: gotten from that ordinal number and that operation. Next we have a level 3 operation that defines in terms of each level 2 operation the level 2 operation that assigns to each level 1 operation the level 1 operation that assigns to each ordinal number the smallest ordinal number that's larger than any ordinal number that can be gotten from that ordinal number, that level 1 operation, and that level 2 operation. Of course other ordinal numbers such as the Church-Kleene ordinal which is too large to visualize still have the property that the one after it can be described as the successor of it.

Comment: It's just that the Church-Kleene ordinal can't be gotten just by using members of the sequence. The ones that can be gotten that way are the ordinal numbers smaller than epsilon_naught. Some people don't go much further than the ordinal numbers that can be described using the Veblin Hierarchy. However, if you construct epsilon_zero the way I did. Then getting to those describable by the Veblin Hierarchy is a very miniscule advancement compared to constructing epsilon zero from scratch the way I did. Epsilon zero doesn't seem nearly as large as it could have because of the such extreme power of

Comment: ordinal exponentation.

Comment: I know omega raised to the power of an ordinal number is defined by transfinite induction. However, if you think how to break down the transfinite inductive definition of any ordinal number smaller than epsilon zero using using ordinal exponentation notation to determine what the ordinal number actually is, you will find that the description is quite advanced and uses operations from my sequence of operations that I described earlier.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The standard way to visualize $\epsilon_0$ is by the [Hydra game](http://math.andrej.com/2008/02/02/the-hydra-game/). Here the elements of $\epsilon_0$ are visualized as isomorphism classes of rooted finite trees. The inequality can be described by the "cutting off heads" rule: The tree $T_1$ is greater than $T_2$ is there is a series of head cuttings which reduces $T_1$ to $T_2$.  Writing out the inequality relationship between trees directly is a pain, see my [blogpost](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/12/07/the-technical-part-of-godels-proof/). If you turn those nested sets into trees in the obvious way, you get the Hydra game.

I am told that most people do not find it intuitive that the Hydra game ends. I find that, once I've played a few rounds (try this [applet](http://math.andrej.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/Hydra/hydraApplet.html)) I find it "obvious", although writing down an actual proof is still painful.

As far as an actual proof, you should directly show the following: Let $X$ be a totally ordered set. Let $\omega^X$ be the set of functions $X \to \omega$ which are $0$ for almost all $x \in X$, ordered as follows: Let $f$ and $g$ be distinct elements of $\omega^X$ and let $x$ be the greatest element of $x$ for which $f(x)\neq g(x)$. Then $f<g$ if and only if $f(x) < g(x)$. Then $\omega^X$ is well ordered.
So every tower of $\omega$'s is well ordered and, $\epsilon_0$, being the union of all such towers, is also well-ordered.

---

By the way, you don't ask this, but you might be curious what happens when you try to write out this proof within PA. Recall that PA can't directly talk about subsets of $\omega$. The statement that $\omega$ is well-ordered is encoded as an axiom schema. Let $\phi(x, y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_N)$ be any statement with variables $x$ and $y_i$ running through $\omega$. Then PA has the following axiom:
$$\forall y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n \in \omega: \left( \exists x \in \omega : \phi(x, y_{\bullet}) \implies \exists x' \in \omega : \left( \phi(x', y_{\bullet}) \wedge \forall x \in \omega \left( \phi(x, y_{\bullet}) \implies x \geq x' \right) \right) \right).$$
Please read this axiom until you understand that, in English, it says "For all $y$'s, if there is some $x$ obeying $\phi$, then there is a least $x$ obeying $\phi$."

Let's call this axiom $W(\phi, \omega)$. We'll use similar notation with $\omega$ replaced by other sets. Here is a challenging and important exercise: Let $X$ be an ordered set. Let $\phi$ be a statement about $\omega^X$, which may have other variables $y_i$ in it. Construct a specific statement $\sigma(\phi)$ about $X$, with other variables $z_i$ running through $X$, such that
$$  W(\sigma(\phi), X) \implies W(\phi, \omega^X)  \quad (*).$$

For every specific $\phi$, the statement $(*)$ can be proved in PA. Since $W(\psi, \omega)$ is a axiom of PA for every $\psi$, we can prove $W(\phi, \omega^{\omega^{\ldots^{\omega}}})$ in PA for any $\phi$ and any specific height of tower.

But, in order to show that $\epsilon_0$ is well-ordered, we need to show that $W(\phi, \omega^{\omega^{\ldots^{\omega}}})$ simultaneously for every height of tower. Tracing through the arguments here, you would need to know $W(\phi, \omega)$, $W(\sigma(\phi), \omega)$, $W(\sigma(\sigma(\phi)), \omega)$, $W(\sigma^3(\phi), \omega)$ and so forth. As a human mathematician, that probably doesn't bother you at all. But, in the formal system PA, any proof can only use finitely many axioms. So there is no way to write a proof which uses all of the axioms $W(\sigma^k(\phi), X)$, for all $k$.

Of course, this doesn't show that some more clever argument couldn't prove that $\epsilon_0$ is well-ordered while working with PA; you need the Kirby-Paris theorem for that. (More precisely Kirby-Paris plus Godel shows that, if PA proves $\epsilon_0$ is well-ordered, then PA is inconsistent.) But I find that seeing this obstacle, the need to use infinitely many versions of the well-ordering axiom, clarifies my understanding of what is gong on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (although I didn't write the question). I was searching for these proofs, but that was rather hard to find. Most proofs (such as in the Wikipedia), stop by saying that it is well-ordered.



Comment: Hi David,
I'll definitely need a couple of days to digest your blog's post and this answer, but from what I already managed to understant, it is great and very clear!!
thank you a lot!

Comment: David, I think you answered another question from me:

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25430/can-goodsteins-theorem-been-proven-with-first-order-pa-constructive-omega-rule

Give the proof, I think the answer to that question is Yes! FOL + PA extended with COR can prove Goodsteins-theorem.

Comment: This answer is over a year old, but for the sake of future readers:

This is false: "Let $X$ be a totally ordered set. Let $\omega^X$ be the set of functions $X \to \omega$ which are $0$ for almost all $x \in X$, ordered lexicographically. Then $\omega^X$ is well ordered."

Just look in $\omega^\omega$: the characteristic functions of the singletons.

The correct version requires $X$ to be well ordered and gives $\omega^X$ the reverse lexicographic order, i.e., compares functions at their greatest coordinate of disagreement.

Comment: I finally went and fixed the error David Milovich points out; thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 5):

In the course of writing an [expository article](http://timothychow.net/consistent.pdf) on the consistency of arithmetic, I was led to try to explain $\epsilon_0$ in as "finitary a manner" as possible.  Here is what I came up with, inspired greatly by the account in Torkel Franzen's book *Inexhaustibility: A Non-Exhaustive Account*, as well as the LISP programming language.

Define a
*list*
to be either an empty sequence—denoted
by ( ) and referred to as the empty list—or, recursively, a
finite   nonempty   sequence   of   lists.  If we write a list by separating the
constituent elements by commas and enclosing the entire sequence with parentheses,
then   for   example,
(( ), ( ), ( ))  and  ((( ), ( )), ((( ), (( ), ( ))), ( )))  are  lists.
The number of constituent lists is called its *length*
(it is
zero for the empty list). If
$a$
is a nonempty list, then we
write $a[i]$ for the
$i$th constituent list of $a$,
 where $i$ ranges
from 1 to the length of $a$.

Next, recursively define a total ordering $\le$
on lists as
follows  (it is essentially  a lexicographic ordering). Let
$a$ and $b$
be lists, with lengths
$m$ and $n$
respectively. If $m\le n$ and $a[i] = b[i]$  for all $1\le i \le m$
(this condition is vacuously
satisfied if
 $m=0$), then $a\le b$. Otherwise, there exists some $i$
such that
$a[i] \ne b[i]$; let $i_0$
be the least such number, and
declare $a< b$ if $a[i_0] < b[i_0]$.

Finally, recursively define a list $a$
to be an
*ordinal* (or more precisely, an *ordinal below $\epsilon_0$*, but I will just say ordinal for short)
if all
its  constituent  lists  are  ordinals  and $a[i] \ge a[j]$ whenever $i<j$.
(In particular, the empty list is an ordinal, since the
condition is vacuously satisfied.)

As an exercise, you can verify that the ordinals ((( ))) and ((( ), ( ))) and ((( )), (( ))) are, in standard notation, the same as $\omega$, $\omega^2$, and $\omega \cdot 2$ respectively.

My personal opinion is that the usual ways of defining $\epsilon_0$ make it seem mind-bogglingly infinitary, but the above definition makes it clear that any particular ordinal is just a special type of finite list of finite lists of finite lists of … of finite lists.  Not very infinitary at all.

The proof that there is no infinite descending sequence is not particularly mind-boggling either, in this language.  Rather than type it out here, I refer you to the proof of Theorem 1 in my expository article.

I find that after understanding this proof, the hard thing to wrap my head around is how it can possibly be true that PA does *not* prove that there is no infinite descending sequence.  My current gut feeling is that PA seems weirdly weak, because it cannot even formalize a proof as simple as this one.

Comment: *"My personal opinion is that the usual ways of defining $\epsilon_0$ make it seem mind-bogglingly infinitary"* .... My personal opinion is that every recursive ordinal is fundamentally finitary (but only once we understand it and realise that the larger structures involved in the def. are merely to help us in keeping track of complex steps of visualisation). So I would personally use the term **complex** instead of **infinitary** in the given quote since, in my personal opinion, making a divide of finitary/infinitary at some arbitrary point isn't quite right. But anyway, just my thoughts.

Comment: But perhaps, "finitary" doesn't have a fixed meaning anyway. Because, based on various essays (on related topics) I have read/skimmed, it seems that its precise meaning is subject to interpretation. But honestly, I don't really know. Anyway, there is also another nice exposition for an (easy) notation for $\epsilon_0$ in the book "Where is the godel point hiding". (I haven't read it though)

Comment: @SSequence : I agree; "finitary" has no fixed meaning. Back in Gentzen's day, what we now call primitive recursive arithmetic (PRA) was considered finitary, and people hoped for a finitary consistency proof of PA. Since induction up to $\epsilon_0$ was the only non-PRA ingredient in Gentzen's consistency proof, he discussed in detail whether such an induction could be considered finitary. So $\epsilon_0$ and the word finitary (or its German cognates) have a long history of being connected to each other. Even today, I hear suspicions voiced about $\epsilon_0$ being illegitimately infinitary.

Comment: @SSequence I think we need to distinguish between "has a finitary description" and "has a *fully analyzable* finitary description" - the point isn't that the index for a Turing machine building a copy of $\epsilon_0$ need be "infinitary" somehow, but rather the (argued) lack of finitistic methods for establishing the "fundamental facts" about such an index (e.g. "is well-founded"). Of course this just introduces more subjectivity into the issue - even ignoring finitaritude(?), what does "fully analyzable" (/"fundamental facts") mean? - but I think it's a meaningful distinction.

Comment: @TimothyChow The impression I had about this term was similar. That is, it seems to me that nearly all (usual) forms of "finitism" accept PRA (something that I have seen mentioned numerous times in relation to finitism). And after that they accept more principles depending on circumstances or arguments directly presented to them. Anyway it is good to have it clarified, since a lot of the survey books on phil. seem to be very formal about it and don't mention this kind of thing very clearly.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I don't disagree with what you are saying (except adding some personal opinions). Something I would briefly point out though. It doesn't seem too far-fetched 
(though a bit speculative) to me that traditional def. of well-order makes it a bit harder to accept than it has to be. Personally, the way I "internalise" a well-order of $\mathbb{N}$ with certain order-type $\alpha$ is to consider some $\beta>\alpha$ ("some" $\beta$ which I can "reasonably" accept) and then content myself that I can use 
quantification over values ranging over $\beta$. It's just me though.

Comment: @SSequence If I understand what you're saying correctly that's still not enough. Saying that $\alpha$ is well-founded involves quantification over *subsets* of $\alpha$, not elements; going up to a longer ordering won't help necessarily. Now maybe by "traditional def. of well-order makes it a bit harder to accept than it has to be" you mean that you view the ability to quantify over elements as more relevant than the absence of descending sequences but that doesn't match up with how ordinals are used - e.g. PRA + "$\epsilon_0$ is *well-founded*" proves Con(PA) using "well-founded" essentially.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Sorry I wasn't fully clear. Just a brief clarification. What I meant was that the traditional def. (based on what I have read) for well-order can be given as: (i) the underlying relation is a linear order (ii) there are no infinite descending sequences. The way I feel more comfortable (just personally) is to drop (ii) and replace it with another condition (which isn't too hard to write), which just uses quantification over a large enough ordinal (instead of subsets). But then, I think, one would have to prove (ii) as a result instead of having it as definition.

Comment: Anyway, just different way of internalisation (based on personal preference). This is probably going a bit off-topic perhaps.

Comment: @SSequence Even ignoring details (I don't actually see what your (ii) should be) there's a serious issue here: "quantification over a large enough ordinal" OK, how do you **finitistically** (a) find such a sufficiently gigantic ordinal and (b) demonstrate that quantification over it has the desired properties? In a precise sense there's not going to be a way around this: the set of indices for computable well-orderings is $\Pi^1_1$ complete and moreover any $\Sigma^1_1$ set of indices for computable well-orderings doesn't contain indices for arbitrarily large computable well-orderings. (contd)

Comment: I recommend taking a look at Theorem 2 in my expository paper. Though it isn't exactly how Gentzen did it, the consistency of PA can be proved by taking as an axiom a statement that certain descending sequences eventually stabilize. Conceptually this may be more acceptable (than the standard approach) to those who are uneasy about quantifying over arbitrary subsets.

Comment: *(Incidentally, this is - as often happens - paralleled at the level of descriptive set theory: the set of reals coding well-orderings is coanalytic-complete, and in particular not analytic.)* So there is a fundamental complexity that you can't escape from here, no matter how you frame the definition of "well-ordering" - at some level there's going to be a second-order quantifier folded in. The hoped-for finitistic (or otherwise tame) argument at some level consists of arguing that *in the particular case of $\epsilon_0$* something special happens, but the facts above indicate (cont'd)

Comment: that whatever that argument is, it can't hold uniformly for all computable ordinals. Tl;dr: I claim that for mathematically precise reasons there is no way to "trivially" kill finitistic concerns about $\epsilon_0$, we have to actually do some work (or decide we don't care about those concerns).

Comment: @NoahSchweber by "large enough", I actually mean just larger (or possibly equal) than $\alpha$(the order-type of a well-order of $\mathbb{N}$). Anyway, this would go pretty off-topic. Even assuming standard definition, for simple enough notations for very small elements, we can actually see rather clearly that there are no infinite descending sequences using basic arguments. Below is an example for $\omega^2$ (admittedly this "naive" way would become harder and harder to see in detail with larger elements). For any well-order with order-type $\omega^2$ suppose someone claims that (cont.)

Comment: there is such an infinite descending sequence $\alpha_0$,$\alpha_1$,$\alpha_2$,..... etc. Surely(?) then one can convince that person that there "must" exist a total function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $position(f(n))≥\alpha_n$ (for all $n$). Here position is the "obvious" bijection function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\alpha$. If we have a nice enough notation for $\omega^2$, we will have an upper-bound on number of descents(roughly) as something
like $f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+.....+f(f(0)−1)+f(f(0))$. But probably, this would get pretty complex as we go higher. Anyway....

Comment: By "nice enough", I mean satisfying certain nice properties.

Comment: @SSequence I don't see how any of what you're saying is not ultimately circular, but you're right - this isn't the right place for a discussion. A question/chatroom at MSE might be better (I actually don't know whether MO has chatrooms).

Comment: Incidentally (for the sake of avoiding confusion), the expression I wrote in last comment is somewhat off (though I hope the rest of the comment is clear).

Comment: @NoahSchweber This is probably a little late but regarding: "Personally, the way I "internalise" a well-order of $\mathbb{N}$ with certain order-type $\alpha$ is to consider some $\beta>\alpha$ ("some" $\beta$ which I can "reasonably" accept) and then content myself that I can use quantification over values ranging over $\beta$." I think that this particular comment of mine (and the comment that followed after this one) were not well-thought out. I did have something in mind though but it was a bit different (and it doesn't seem quite relevant to the actual point of question).

Answer (score 4):

David Speyer's [blog post](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/12/07/the-technical-part-of-godels-proof/), inspired by the MO question referenced by Francois Dorais in the comments, contains a detailed answer to this question.

Comment: The blog post gives in detail how to encode ordinals. However, there is no proof that there isn't a infinite descending chain. 

Answer (score 0):

This is meant to be a simple but perhaps slightly alternative answer. Define two functions $V_1:\epsilon_0 \rightarrow \epsilon_0$ and $V_2:\epsilon_0 \rightarrow \epsilon_0$.

For any given $x$, define $\gamma$ as the smallest ordinal such that $\gamma \cdot \omega > x$. And now define:

$V_1(x)=0 \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad when\; x<\omega$

$V_1(x)=\alpha \;such\; that\; \omega^\alpha=\gamma \qquad \quad when\; x \geq\omega$

$V_2(x)=Pre(x) \qquad \qquad \quad  when\; x<\omega$

$V_2(x)=Lsub(\gamma,x) \qquad \qquad  when \; x \geq\omega $

Here $Pre$ stands for usual predecessor function (with output $0$ on $0$). And $Lsub:\epsilon_0 \times \epsilon_0 \rightarrow \epsilon_0$ is defined as: $$Lsub(\alpha,\beta)=0 \qquad if \, \alpha > \beta$$ $$Lsub(\alpha,\beta)=\{\,y\in \epsilon_0\,|\,\alpha+y=\beta\,\} \qquad if \, \alpha \le \beta$$

Note that for all values in the domain (except $x=0$), we have $V_1(x)<x$ and $V_2(x)<x$. Furthermore, we can observe that for any non-zero ordinals $\alpha_1,\alpha_2<\epsilon_0$ (where $\alpha_1 \neq \alpha_2$) it is not the case that $V_1(\alpha_1)=V_1(\alpha_2)$ and $V_2(\alpha_1)=V_2(\alpha_2)$.

And with this we can associate with every ordinal less than $\epsilon_0$ a "unique" finite tree. Each node will have either "two" or "no" child nodes. Also each node is individually completely unmarked (no number/label etc. associated with it).

For example, for any $\alpha<\epsilon_0$ we can define the left-subtree as  the tree of $V_1(\alpha)$ and right-subtree as the tree of $V_2(\alpha)$. Furthermore, the tree for $0$ can be defined just as a single (unmarked) node. I think one can use (transfinite) induction to show that for any non-zero ordinals $\alpha_1,\alpha_2<\epsilon_0$ (where $\alpha_1 \neq \alpha_2$), their representations as trees will be different.

Perhaps to someone who is "very skeptical" that $\epsilon_0$ can be well-ordered at all (in terms of finite objects) one could try to convince them that the functions $V_1$ and $V_2$ are simple enough that applying any possible combination of them (as composition) on a given $\alpha<\epsilon_0$ would return to $0$ in finite attempts.

For just applying $V_1$ it is very easy to see. For example, $V_1(\omega^{\omega^\omega})=\omega^\omega$, $V_1(\omega^\omega)=\omega$, $V_1(\omega)=1$, $V_1(1)=0$. Similarly $V_1(\omega^{\omega^2})=\omega^2$. So it seems to me that application $V_1$ can be thought of as just "eating up" the towers (and finite number of towers will be eaten up with finite number of attempts).

But the situation seems more complex for a combination and convincing someone who is "very skeptical" might require a more intuitive/visualisable explanation that **any** combination (of $V_1$ and $V_2$ applied as composition) would also always go back to $0$ in finite attempts.

---

But it seems that a good way to see whether there is no infinite descending chain is to write down a complex game where the person claiming the chain is supposed to provide a new (natural) number at each stage. And eventually showing that no matter what numbers are provided, the game has to terminate.

**Edit:** I noticed the faulty reasoning in my previous post. I have removed it.

P.S. I noticed this question under the "Related" list. I hope it is fine to bump an old question (especially if it has an accepted answer) for a slightly different kind of answer.