# Can one really construct an "ordinal table"?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, proof-theory

Many books describe how one can construct "by hand" a table of ordinals $1,\ 2,\ \ldots,\ \omega,\ \omega +1,\ \omega +2,\ \ldots,\ \omega\cdot 2,\ \omega\cdot 2 +1,\ \ldots,\ \omega^{2},\ \ldots,\ \omega^{3},\ \ldots\ \omega^{\omega},\ \ldots,\ \omega^{\omega^{\omega}},\ \ldots, \epsilon_{0},\ \ldots$.
But does this span the entire ordinal class? For some reason I can't seem to prove it. Is there an easy way to see that?
Thanks!

Comment: There are uncountably many countable ordinals, so eventually you run out of descriptions. But not before you've got to some extraordinarily large and complicated ordinals ...

Comment: That rather depends on what your final ellipsis means ...  :-)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_countable_ordinal.

Comment: @Richard Thanks for the article reference. So apparently the table doesn't even exhaust countable ordinals...

Comment: The final ellipsis was a bit vague, but meant roughly that as you get bigger and bigger, it gets harder and harder to describe the ordinals, but that people have come up with (to me) very ingenious ways of getting further than one might as a nonexpert have thought possible.

Comment: I should add that all the time I am talking about countable ordinals, since I think that makes the question more interesting.

Comment: Sorry, Tim, I was referring to kwan's final ellipsis, not yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since ordinal numbers have a unique division, logarithm and subtraction properties, when given an ordinal $\alpha$ you can write any other ordinal as a finite polynomial in $\alpha$, when $\alpha = \omega$ you get what's known as "Cantor normal form of $\gamma$ for the base $\omega$".

I.e., any ordinal $\gamma$ can be written as a finite sum: $$\gamma = \sum_{i=0}^n \omega^{\alpha_i}\cdot\beta_i$$
Where $\alpha_i$ is a decreasing chain of ordinals, and $\beta_i$ is finite.

(More generally, you can take some base $\zeta$ and then $\beta_i < \zeta$)

Thing is that we only have a finite number of symbols, so at most we can represent (uniquely) a countable number of numbers, since we have a proper class of ordinals, which is a mind boggling concept of infinitude, you obviously can't write them all. But still, any given ordinal can be presented as a finite polynomial in $\omega$, thus spanning the table discussed.

Comment: For many ordinals $\alpha$, including all infinite cardinals (viewed as initial ordinals), the ordinal exponentiation $\omega^\alpha$ is just $\alpha$ again, meaning that the Cantor normal form of these ordinals $\alpha$ is just $\omega^\alpha\cdot 1$, which doesn't provide a representation of $\alpha$ in terms of smaller ordinals. That is, you need $\alpha$ to represent $\alpha$. These ordinals are called the $\epsilon$-numbers, and the smallest is known as $\epsilon_0$. The next is $\epsilon_1$ and so on.

Comment: @Joel: More so, this "normal form" for these ordinals isn't unique.  The CNFT only applies to ordinals less than epsilon-0.  

Comment: @Charles: If I recall correctly, there is a logarithm for ordinal numbers, it might be a fixed-point (i.e. $\log_\omega\epsilon_0=\epsilon_0$  but there's still a logarithm. Ergo, given $\epsilon_0$ you have that the CNF for it would be $\omega^{\epsilon_0}$. 

To clarify my point, there's no condition given for $\alpha_i$ (assuming the notation from my answer) except that it would be a decreasing sequence of ordinals. Joel just remarked something that I skipped, that there could be a situation in which $n=0,\ \alpha_0=\gamma$ and $\beta0=1$.

Comment: Charles, to my knowledge, it *is* unique, and it works for all ordinals, even uncountable ordinals.

Comment: But I agree that the normal form below $\epsilon_0$ is indeed much nicer, because it is exactly in that region that the ordinals used in the CNF of an ordinal are always strictly less than the ordinal. Indeed, if one iterates the CNF by applying it also to the exponents, then one needs only finitely many natural numbers to represent any ordinal below $\epsilon_0$. This idea is central to the proof of Goodstein's theorem, mentioned  in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18100/theorems-with-unexpected-conclusions/18107#18107.

Comment: Oh, I see now that you may have meant that this *iterated* representation is not unique, since for $\epsilon$-numbers, we have $\omega^\alpha=\omega^{\oemga^\alpha}$, precisely because  $\omega^\alpha=\alpha$. I agree.

Comment: $\omega^\alpha=\omega^{\omega^\alpha}$.

Comment: @Joel: Oh yes, I had misremembered the CNFT.  To put things in lambda-calculus terms, the CNFT gives a head normal form, not the recursive full normal form.  @Asaf, sorry.

Comment: @Charles: It's fine, I think we all learn from these small mistakes.

Comment: Is this the reason the class of all ordinal numbers is mind boggling infinite? For any set, there is an even larger set. The class of all ordinal numbers is so large that it's larger than every well-orderable set.

Comment: Did you mean something like "All ordinal numbers can be expressed as a descending sum of nonzero finite multiples of powers of $\omega$. However, since we don't already have a notation for all ordinal numbers, this process doesn't define a notation for all ordinal numbers?"